# Migrate Apache Web Site With SQL Instance to New Server

Tags: java, sql-server, apache, tomcat

We have an old 2003 server thats running an Apache Site with an SQL Database on the backend.  This was setup/configured prior to me starting so I don't know awhole lot about it, except that the data needs to be accessible for a bit longer and i've been given the task of migrating it to a new server to get it off of 2003.

I'm curious how I would go about doing this?  For the site I have installed Apache on the new server and then just copied and pasted the Apache directory to the new server and the site seems to be accessible.

I've also backed the database up and restored it to a new SQL Server, but where i'm lost is in how I point Apache to the new database server?

I read somewhere that to do this it'll require a JDBC Driver for connecting Apache to SQL.  I'm not sure how to go about doing this this?

Any help would be appreciated, and I apologize if my question is hard to understand.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "Apache" above do you mean "Tomcat"?  I know that it is "Apache Tomcat" but I want to make sure I'm understanding your question.  If so, what version of Tomcat are you coming from and what version are you moving to?

Comment: I do see TomCat installed and running/started as well yes.  It's TomCat version 2.3.0 and i've installed the same version on the new server to try to keep the versions in line as to not mess anything up with the migration

Comment: Something isn't quite correct here.  Tomcat started out as version 3 so I'm not sure what you've got that is 2.3.0.  If it is Tomcat then in the base installation directory there is a `logs` directory.  There may be a ton of files there but there should be a file named `catalina.out`.  That should give you a bit more information about what you've got currently.

Comment: How about TomCat 5.5, does that sound better. =)

Comment: Much better.  While it's no longer supported the basic configuration of a database connection hasn't changed in years.  Take a look at the [Tomcat 5.5 docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/index.html), specifically [JNDI Resources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) and [JNDI Resources How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).  These should help you understand where to configure Tomcat to talk to your database.

Comment: I will take a look and report back.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction